# error: The named parameter 'children' isn't defined

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, defined

[i keep on getting this error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCvnT.png)

i tried on converting it to child and then it keeps on getting an error. heres my code:

```
  // TODO: Build a grid of cards (102)
      children: <Widget>[
      Card(
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 18.0 / 11.0,
              child: Image.asset('assets/diamond.png'),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 12.0, 16.0, 8.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Title'),
                  const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                  Text('Secondary Text'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
],
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error because the ')' is typed before children. Also, You can't use children parameter 2 times.

Comment: what will i do?

Comment: You need to get Gridview and other widget such as Column inside of Column widget. Also, if you want to add this children's with Gridview's children then append the children with Gridview's children

Answer (score 0):

You can use variable `List<Widget>` for Item of GridView

Example:

```
'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  List<Widget> listWidget = [
    Card(
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: 18.0 / 11.0,
            child: Image.asset('assets/diamond.png'),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 12.0, 16.0, 8.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Title'),
                const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                Text('Secondary Text'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        childAspectRatio: 8 / 9,
        children: listWidget,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```